# PHP Composer & other Docker services start-up sequence problem

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

`sp-composer` is a one-time service that builds the PHP Composer vendor volume into a volume `composer`; this takes a few minutes as it downloads the packages. As I (partly) understand it, dependent services in the same composer/stack file don't wait for the RUN task to complete, so they start up with an empty `composer` volume and they never see it subsequently as populated (for some reason).

The current work-around is an 8 second sleep in the production start-up sequence, with the Swarm stack file split into one just for Composer, and the other for the rest. Occasionally we need to increase the delay. This is of course terrible and should be fixed.

There are many posts about using a healthcheck to delaying a service based on a dependency such as a network service (e.g. a database) but `sp-composer` is a service that just runs and then exits.

We just need to delay the rest of the sequence starting until `sp-composer` has exited.  It occured to me that `docker wait` (should?) solve half the problem, but we still need the stack file split into two parts, and two times `docker stack deploy`.

What is the current best practice to fix this situation?

For reference, this is the Dockerfile in question:

```
FROM php:7.1
RUN apt-get update \
    && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive \
    && apt-get install -y libxml2-dev zlib1g-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-install soap zip
COPY . /composer
WORKDIR /composer
RUN php ./composer.phar install --no-dev --no-interaction --optimize-autoloader
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the proper approach is editing the Dockerfiles of the containers that depend on the PHP Composer container so that they wait a little before running.

The easy solution would be to add sleep to the RUN command (e.g. `RUN sleep 5s; entrypoint.sh`).

A cleaner solution is to periodically verify inside the entrypoint script that the volume is populated correctly. Something like:

```
$VOLUME_POPULATED = false
while [[ $VOLUME_POPULATED != true ]]
do
# check if volume is populated
sleep 5s
done

# execute rest of command
```

Using either method, you won't need two Swarm files since the containers are built to wait for the prerequisites to be completed.

Also, if you are open to trying other orchestrations tools, I would suggest giving Kubernetes a try as it's de facto standard for container orchestration. In particular, [init containers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/) are built for the problem you are facing.

Comment: +1 on the entrypoint script. You could enhance it by using exponential backoff and limiting the number of retries. As per init-containers and kube: note that this would mean that the sp-composer and the real workload run in the same pod, scale at the same time etc. This might not be what you want, especially as the sp-container shouldn't run all the time.

Comment: Not necessarily, you could use a Job to run the sp-container, and a Pod that contains the app container + an init container that makes sure the Job has been completed. The Job and Pod could then scale independently. Unlike the posted solution, you don't have to edit the app container, which could be a challenge if you aren't the one that built the image.

Comment: We own the images. Kubernetes is definitely on the agenda - just have had to moderate spending time on infra. Init containers are ideal - thanks for the pointers!